# how to excecute Jquery functions in a linear fashion? (sequentially)

Tags: jquery, sequential

I am not sure how to describe this. I have a couple of divs on a page, something like:

```
<div id="Content">
    <div id="SubContent" class="LoremIpsum">
        some lorem ipsum text here
    </div>

    <div id="SubContent" class="Shakespeare" style="display:none">
        Macbeth story here
    </div>
</div>

<a href="Javascript:Void(0);" onClick="ChangeStory">Change</a>
```

So now, When I click on that "**Change**"  link, I want the LoremIpsum div to slide up, and AFTER it finishes sliding up, I want Shakespeare div to slide down.

Currently, I have:

```
function ChangeStory(){
    $('.LoremIpsum').slideUp(); 
$('.Shakespeare').slideDown();
}
```

Instead of the events happening one after the other, they are happening simultaneously. I tried to insert some timing delay but did not quite work out well. Any ideas on how to run them one after the other?

many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) callback (all animations have them), like this:

```
function ChangeStory(){
  $('.LoremIpsum').slideUp(function() {
    $('.Shakespeare').slideDown();
  }); 
}
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/XCmQt/1/). Or, just add a [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) with the duration of the other animation, though this would only be preferred in certain situations:

```
function ChangeStory(){
  $('.LoremIpsum').slideUp();
  $('.Shakespeare').delay(400).slideDown();
}
```

[Try that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/XCmQt/2/).

---

Also look at binding your handler unobtrusively, for example change your link to this:

```
<a href="#" class="ChangeStory">Change</a>
```

And your JavaScript to this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.ChangeStory").click(function (e){
    $('.LoremIpsum').slideUp(function() {
      $('.Shakespeare').slideDown();
    }); 
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent scrolling to top
  });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/XCmQt/).

Comment: whoa, that looks great, but what If I want to pass a parameter to slideUp? like, **.slideUp("slow");** ? will adding **return "slow"** after the **.slideDown();** work? I tried it already, didnt seem to do much. thanks.

Comment: @LocustHorde - if you want both to be slow, it'd look like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/XCmQt/3/ It's the first parameter to both `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`...the callback is the second parameter you're using for `.slideUp()`.

Comment: oh that worked! Great!! Just reminds me that there are stil massive lots to learn! thanks again!